# Codeigniter and sockets

Tags: php, codeigniter, sockets

I'm new in codeigniter. I've created little, simple socket chat server. I'm running it from Shell. When there is a new connection I'm making new object of class, which is in codeigniter's libraries. In this class constructor I'm trying to make instance

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

but there is error:

```
Call to undefined function get_instance();
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not loading the library through CI itself, but rather through some external include. get_instance() is a core function of CI, and it does not exist natively outside of CI.